# login page in shinyapp doesn't work when hit the sign in button

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

so i try to create login page using shinyapp, but when sign in button clicked, the dashboardBody doesn't appear, i try so hard but i could't find where is wrong with my code, so here my code :

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)
library(DT)
library(lubridate)
library(shinyalert)
library(stringr)
library(rprintf)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(sodium)
```

and on the login page or i using javascript like this :

```
loginpage <- div(id = "loginpage", style = "width: 300px; max-width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 20px;",
                 wellPanel(
                   tags$h2("", class = "text-center", style = "padding-top: 0;color:#333; font-weight:600;"),
                   textInput("userName", placeholder="Username", label = tagList(icon("user"), "Username")),
                   passwordInput("passwd", placeholder="Password", label = tagList(icon("unlock-alt"), "Password")),
                   br(),
                   div(
                     style = "text-align: center;",
                     actionButton("login", "SIGN IN", style = "color: white; background-color:#3c8dbc;
                                 padding: 10px 15px; width: 150px; cursor: pointer;
                                 font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600;"),
                     shinyjs::hidden(
                       div(id = "nomatch",
                           tags$p("Oops! Incorrect username or password!",
                                  style = "color: red; font-weight: 600;
                                            padding-top: 5px;font-size:16px;",
                                  class = "text-center"))),
                     br(),
                     
                   ))
)
credentials = data.frame(
  username_id = c("myuser", "myuser1"),
  passod   = sapply(c("mypass", "mypass1"),password_store),
  permission  = c("basic", "advanced"), 
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE, compact = TRUE, uiOutput("logoutbtn")),
  sidebar <- dashboardSidebar( id = "side",disable = TRUE, uiOutput("sidebarpanel"),
  body <- dashboardBody(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    useShinyjs(),
    uiOutput("body"),
    fluidRow(align = "center",
             setBackgroundImage(
               src = "backgroundlogin.jpg", 
               shinydashboard = TRUE),
             
             column(width = 4, offset = 4, style = "margin: 0;position: absolute;
                        top: 50%;left: 50%;-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);transform: translate(-50%, -50%);",
                    
                    img(src='logosmall.png', width= '66.7%'),
                    loginpage
             )
    )
  )
)
```

after that on the server :

this is for condition when the user get to login :

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  login = FALSE
  USER <- reactiveValues(login = login)
  #pengecekan kondisi
  observe({ 
    if (USER$login == FALSE) {
      if (!is.null(input$login)) {
        if (input$login > 0) {
          Username <- isolate(input$userName)
          Password <- isolate(input$passwd)
          if(length(which(credentials$username_id==Username))==1) { 
            pasmatch  <- credentials["passod"][which(credentials$username_id==Username),]
            pasverify <- password_verify(pasmatch, Password)
            if(pasverify) {
              USER$login <- TRUE
              if(USER$login == TRUE){
                source("global.R")
                print("Berhasil")
              }else{
                shinyjs::toggle(id = "nomatch", anim = TRUE, time = 1, animType = "fade")
                shinyjs::delay(3000, shinyjs::toggle(id = "nomatch", anim = TRUE, time = 1, animType = "fade"))
              }
            } else {
              shinyjs::toggle(id = "nomatch", anim = TRUE, time = 1, animType = "fade")
              shinyjs::delay(3000, shinyjs::toggle(id = "nomatch", anim = TRUE, time = 1, animType = "fade"))
            }
          } else {
            shinyjs::toggle(id = "nomatch", anim = TRUE, time = 1, animType = "fade")
            shinyjs::delay(3000, shinyjs::toggle(id = "nomatch", anim = TRUE, time = 1, animType = "fade"))
          }
        } 
      }
    }    
  })
 #untuk tombol logout
  output$logoutbtn <- renderUI({
    req(USER$login)
    tags$li(a(icon("sign-out-alt"), "Logout", 
              href="javascript:window.location.reload(true)"),
            class = "pull-right",
            status = "secondary",
            size = "sm",
            style = "background-color: Transparent; background-repeat:no-repeat; 
      border: none; cursor:pointer; overflow: hidden;outline:none;")
  })
```

and this the dasboar body, appear when the user success to login from the login form :

```
  output$dashboardBody <- renderUI({
    if (USER$login == TRUE ) {
      bs4TabItems(
        
        # Tab 1: Prospek Management
        bs4TabItem(
          tabName = 'ManageProspek',
          source("01-prospek/prospek_ui.R", local = TRUE)$value
        ),
        # Tab 0: Admin Page
        bs4TabItem(
          tabName = 'adminpage',
          source("00-adminpage/admin_ui.R", local = TRUE)$value
        )
        
      )
      
    }
    else {
      loginpage
    }
  })
  reactive(print(input$tabs)
           
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$tabs,{
    if(input$tabs=="ManageProspek"){
      source("01-prospek/prospek_srv.R",local = TRUE)
    } else if (input$tabs=="adminpage"){
      source("00-adminpage/admin_srv.R",local = TRUE)
    }
    
  })
  
shinyjs::hide(id = "header", anim = FALSE)
shinyjs::hide(id = "side", anim = FALSE)
  
}




# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I have not checked everything because your code is too complex, but I think you have to replace `output$dashboardBody <- renderUI` with `output$body <- renderUI`, since you have `uiOutput("body")` in your UI.

Comment: i have checked and nothing happen